# When virtual table is not the first element of structure?

Tags: arm, vtables, shared-object

Assuming that source code is compiled for ARMv7 architecure using clang (native shared object library for Android, Itanium ABI) what are the cases when virtual table pointer is not the first element of structure?

Comment: I don't know that ARM ABI, but this can happen when the class has multiple inheritance: you can end up with separate a virtual table for each base class. You do normally get a vtable at the start of the structure too, though, just not necessarily the only one.